# Error while installing SSL certificate configuration on AWS server

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, ssl, https

I have configured SSl certificate on AWS EC2 server by following [Step-by-Step procedure to generate a CSR and install an SSL Certificate on a Tomcat web server](https://comodosslstore.com/blog/step-by-step-procedure-to-generate-a-csr-and-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-a-tomcat-web-server.html). And I purchased this SSl certificate from Comodo. But after all installations setup, am not redirecting to my server when I add HTTPS to it.

Please help me out on this issue...

Thank you

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force a redirect from http to https you need this

```
<Connector port="xx" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               redirectPort="443"/>
```